# assembly reference problem--'assembly not referenced' versus type in two assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, ilmerge

I'm having a problem with assembly references.  I have four assemblies:

1. A class library called EncryptionUtils
2. Another class library called PasswordUtils that uses EncryptionUtils
3. Another class library called Toolkit that is an ILMerge of many libraries, including EncryptionUtils
4. A WPF application that uses Toolkit and PasswordUtils

In my WPF app, if I don't include a reference to EncryptionUtils, I get the following error:

> The type 'EncryptionUtils.RSAPublicKey' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'EncryptionUtils, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

However, once I add a reference to the very same EncryptionUtils that both PasswordUtils and Toolkit were built with, I get the following error:

> The type 'EncryptionUtils.MyClass' exists in both 'c:...\EncryptionUtils.dll' and 'c:...\Toolkit.dll'

How do I get out of this catch 22??  Do I have to add all the individual libraries that make up Toolkit to my WPF app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add the libraries to the WPF app individually (which is what I'd tend to recommend) *or* merge `PasswordUtils` into `Toolkit`, and remove the reference to `PasswordUtils`.

You *could* potentially use an extern alias to specify which type you mean - but having the same type available in two assemblies is a bit of a recipe for disaster, IMO.